# uWSGI --chmod-socket doesn't work

Tags: linux, sockets, uwsgi, centos6

I'm spawning uwsgi like this:

`/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --uid uwsgi --chmod-socket=660 --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites --vassals-include /etc/uwsgi/default.ini`

But my socket file is created as `755`:

```
ls -la
srwxr-xr-x   1 uwsgi root     0 Apr  4 12:03 test.sock
stat -c "%a %n" *
755 test.sock
```

Neither `default.ini` or my `test.ini` file contain any chmod or user configuration options.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Emperor has no sockets, so setting the options for it does not make sense. Each vassal has to define it.